# Side up and down Layout using OnTouchListener

Tags: android, android-view, gesture, android-gesture

I have layout where in bottom i have view.layout with list view which i want to take up and down using gesture .like when user click on view and take up it should go up and if he swipe down then should go down .. Like we have drawer left right that way i want top to bottom with say 30% of screen should cover ...

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}



@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
                result = true;
            }
            else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    onSwipeBottom();
                } else {
                    onSwipeTop();
                }
            }
            result = true;

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}
```

}

this code giving just user doing down up etc .. but how i can slide up view .. i want to do viva hand not animation coz in animation when he press it will go up not as his hand goes

Answer (score 0):

You can use Umano Sliding up panel for your work.

Check [this](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

Comment: part from lib any other coz it have too much methods